# iOS SwiftUI: How to show a preview for the swipeAction on a List Row

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, swiftui-swipeactions

I have a SwiftUI List where each row has a swipe action to add item to basket. I want to show users a preview of the swipe action so that they are aware that this action is possible.
How do I go about doing this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(items[index])
                       .padding()
                }
                .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
                    Button("A2B") {
                        print("added")
                    }
                    .tint(.red)
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added an offset to move the row:

```
private struct SwipeActionAnimation: ViewModifier {
    var initialPosition: CGFloat = 0
    var finalOffset: CGFloat = 16
    var animateDuration = 0.4
    var shouldSwipe: Bool = true
    
    @State var isAnimating = false
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: animateDuration)) {
                    self.isAnimating = true
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + animateDuration) {
                    withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: animateDuration)) {
                        self.isAnimating = false
                    }
                }
            }
            .offset(x: isAnimating ? finalOffset : initialPosition)
    }
```

This would be added as a modifier to the row:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
...
}
.modifier(SwipeActionAnimation())
```

But this does not show the swipeActionButton. Just offsets the row and brings it back.
I want to show the preview for the swipeActionButton "Add to Basket" during this animation.

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider the UI. A swipe action seems unusual for an "add to basket" operation and this seems to be causing a discoverability concern. Why not a simple  button on the row?

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the suggestion :) But the action is actually different and specific to my application, which I cannot reveal for confidentiality reasons. I used 'Add to basket' just as an example.